# I am a minor in the US. Will I owe taxes from money earned from a UK based website?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, united-kingdom, international-transfer

My friend and I are co-running a website. He is over 18 and lives in the UK and I'm under 18 and live in the US. He gets all the money from the site into his Paypal, and is going to pay me half.

The amount of money involved is equivalent to the income that would be earned from a part-time or full-time job.

Who would have to pay taxes?
What are the relevant forms or regulations in each country?
What would be the best way to transfer my half from him to me without him being taxed on it?

Comment: Can you provide the approximate dollar amount?

Comment: @Freiheit like 10k-99k around that range a year

Comment: I would hope that you have a company set up fir running the website for tax reasons plus liability + a contract that you get the money. This is too much and too complex to rely on words.

Comment: How are you running this as a partnership or as a plc?

Comment: @Neuromancer Well, we haven't officially registered a company yet. I just said partnership since it's a 50-50 revshare. We are going to hire some more people to work for us once it gets big enough, so then we would have to officially register.

Answer (score 4):

**Given how complicated this transaction would be, I would recommend consulting a tax professional.**

You would have to receive the money as income from your friend(e.g. servicing a website). Work visas, company structure, and payroll considerations (including underage working) would be a few concerns for treating it as waged income. Regardless, consult a professional.

Receiving the money as income would require you filing a form 1099 or similar (depending on how you are classed as either an employee or an independent contractor). Keep in mind there are labor laws in both the US and the UK.

Dependent on the sum involved ($20 from a friend is a lot different than $2,000 from a friend), I would recommend against trying to treat the money transfer as a gift from him to you fraudulently.

Comment: Yeah he said something about if I create an invoice for the programming then he can pay that tax-free, and when I'm 18 he will make it a private company so I can get hired on to it

Comment: If you invoice him, you'll have to declare the money as income to the US government. Seriously though, for that sum of money its worth hiring someone who's job it is to determine tax liability.

Comment: Ok, I'll try and look into some professionals. Are there any online, since it would be hard to visit in person.

Comment: @иσαнcяişтiпσ You need to see a professional face to face at least to start with - I would not trust a professional that only deals over the internet - you will need to prove to them you are not money laundering amoungst other things.

Comment: @Mark But we are in 2 separate countries, which one of us should go see one?

Comment: @иσαнcяişтiпσ Actually both as you have different requirements

Answer (score 2):

If you trust your friend to not try to cheat you, I don't think you necessarily need professional advice on this. It basically breaks down into two parts: how should he pay you, and what do you need to do when you are paid.

For the first part, you should definitely be invoicing him. He can either set up a limited company, or he can [declare himself to be a sole trader](https://www.gov.uk/set-up-sole-trader) and [pay your invoices as expenses](https://www.gov.uk/expenses-if-youre-self-employed). He won't be taxed on that money in the UK as it won't contribute to his profits.

For the second part, you will be liable for tax in the US on the money you receive as you would for any other income you made. I think this would count as [self-employment income in the US](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/self-employment-tax-social-security-and-medicare-taxes) as well, but I don't know the US tax system well.

Comment: How much money would I have to be making to be taxed on it?

Comment: @иσαнcяişтiпσ I think anything above the standard deduction of $12K, but we really need an answer from someone who knows the US tax system well to address that bit. If you are a dependent on your parents' tax return it may complicate things, or perhaps not as this is earned income.

Comment: I just looked it up and I think it's 10.4k

Comment: However if paid as an invoice in UK isn't that subject to VAT - basically you pay VAT or NI on payments.

Comment: @Mark Hmm, true - whether to VAT register the UK business is an interesting question. But I don't think VAT applies to this invoice given the supply is from the US to the UK.

Comment: Im not sure why this was downvoted. Unofficially, the official answer to everything is to consult a professional, but that's not the point of SE sites. The gist of this answer to me appears to be covered well enough with the links provided. UK has to invoice you, you have to declare the taxes here. Simple as that. It seems your concern really focuses on your age. But keep in mind, the legal working age in the USA is like 14, and has certain rules. See here: https://www.dol.gov/general/topic/youthlabor/agerequirements - Are you old enough to work at McDonald's? If so, you're probably fine.

Comment: @иσαнcяişтiпσ: wherever you 'looked up' is out of date; $10.4k was the **2017** filing threshold for single nonsenior _and not a dependent_ (which you _may_ have been) but the reform law passed in Dec. 2017 changed things beginning with 2018 and I don't know if dependent status still makes a difference. I can't find this on the IRS website since it's been redesigned for mobile with almost no content and no nav, and their web tool (ITA) isn't updated yet.

Comment: @KaiQing Yeah I'm 16 so I'm old enough there. Idk why it's being downvoted gave me actual advice, though contacting a pro is always a good idea.

Comment: I think downvoters might reasonably thing I've oversimplified this (e.g. there's the VAT issue). I stand by the core point though that it's really two independent problems: how to split up the income on the UK side and how to deal with the income in the US. Also I think that finding a suitably expert professional can itself be challenging, so it's best to get as far as you can without one first.

Comment: I agree with Ganesh - if I went down the proper path I would never have started any businesses or projects out of fear that I was doing it wrong. Sometimes you just have to do it and figure it out as you go along. When it starts to work, find the professionals who can keep it working. You may have to pay a couple fines here and there but so what?